# Which Tags should be available?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed I wasn't able to tag a question as "add-on" and was forced to use "addon" instead. In ExpressionEngine we use add-on (with a dash/hyphen) and seems like it would be nice to stick with that since it's inline with the ExpressionEngine way of writing it.

Where do we add or apply for tags to be included in this SE?

I'm also wondering if we should be using the ExpressionEngine tag within the ExpressionEngine StackExchange itself or would that be considered overkill to tag EE within EE?

And how would that play into things where people are following a certain tag? Do we follow the ExpressionEngine tag or just the ExpressionEngine SE now?

What are peoples thoughts on this? Hope to have some answers from SE moderators as well if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you had problems creating the tag hyphenated as [add-on](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/add-on). There are already other tags that use hyphens. I renamed the tag.

Also, there will not be an [expressionengine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressionengine) tag. It would be completely redundant and ubiquitous. As the subject of the site itself, 'expressionengine' will likely be blocked... it if hasn't been already.

Finally, rather than starting one massive *"what tags should we have"* thread, why not just let the authors pick their tags as they are needed in actual practice. The users will get it right in the vast, vast majority of cases. It's better to handle the occasional problem and discuss the options when there are actual use cases to consider, rather than trying to anticipate this sort of issue before you've barely gotten started.

Comment: I agree about the list. I guess I just ran into two tags which weren't available and why the confusion. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: If there is the facility to block tags perhaps we could add 'eecms' to the list? I've just manually removed it from about 7 or 8 questions as it was getting to the point where it was one of the most popular tags on the site, despite being completely redundant.

Comment: @DomStubbs For the time being, we should keep editing out these poor tags while the site is still getting established. We may end up needing that filter, but I've found it better to wait and see if it continues to be a problem in actual practice rather than trying to anticipate future problems while the site is still forming. It's just a bit early to make that call. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @RobertCartaino That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We should definitely establish some conventions for new tags and then edit entries as they come in with the conventions and to add new tags as needed.

ideas dashes for multi word tags not underscores, but that could be reversed the idea is to be consistent.

- ecommerce (not the individual modules)
- addon
- templates
- bugs
- conflicts
- upgrade (used for 2.4 to 2.5)
- update (used for 2.5.2 to 2.5.3)
- addon-development
- gallery (not galleries or image-galleries)
- pagination (not paginate)
- ee1
- ee2

Comment: I'd definitely disagree on one point there - tags for unique commerce modules will be very helpful. Most commerce-related answers are going to be specific to a certain module and it will be useful to be able to search for things like '[cartthrob] custom shipping'.

Comment: Dom, I wasn't suggesting that CartThrob or BrilliantRetail not be tags, but rather that ecommerce be a generic tag.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though everyone has the ability to define and edit tags at the moment, so I expect that all of the obvious options (modules, key functionality, addon names) will fill up pretty quickly. In order for tags to be useful it's probably best if they're not too vague, plus there's no use having a bunch of tags that overlap. For example, we already have tags for paginate and pagination, galleries and image-galleries.

Given that everything on the site will relate to EE there's definitely no point in an ExpressionEngine tag (maybe I'm misinterpreting you here?) but ee1 and ee2 tags are probably worth having, especially if you need to look up an EE1 specific fix, as they can be hard to find these days.

Hopefully most of the Stack Overflow EE questions will be posted here instead once the site goes live, but some are bound to slip through the net, so any EE tag subscriptions on SO are probably still worth following.

Comment: +1 on EE1 and EE2 tags!